# Firefox Extension cannot override element events

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm having trouble trying to override a form element's `onsubmit` event. I have no problem adding a listener with `addEventListener`, but for my particular case, I need to **replace** the onsubmit but for some reason when I do, it gives me this error:

```
Error: Component is not available = NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

My code is simply this:

```
gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementById("theform").onsubmit = function() {
   return false;
};
```

Essentially I want to prevent the form from submitting, but this code fails and throws the above error. Using `addEventListener` to return `false` doesn't seem to stop the form from submitting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, the object returned by `getElementById` in an extension is an `XPCNativeWrapper` around the DOM element; it's not the element itself. This results in some important limitations. More details here:

> Assigning to or reading an on* property on an XPCNativeWrapper of a DOM node or Window object will throw an exception. (Use addEventListener instead, and use "event.preventDefault();" in your handler if you used "return false;" before.)

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper#Limitations_of_XPCNativeWrapper